# is it possible to simultaneously record and speech to text in web?

Tags: webrtc, speech-recognition, record

Can the voice be received as input from JavaScript and spring-based web applications and recorded at the same time as the text is converted?

I tried this with webRTC and annyang but failed.

Comment: Yes it is possible. That's quite unfortunate Chrome did apply a lot of restrictions on iframes... The only viable way I found to show a live example is through plnkr.co, and you have to use the "show in popup" view mode... Anyway https://plnkr.co/edit/WdwlG2qNkInGdsSM0c7z?p=preview

Comment: @Kaiido

I failed to run this source.
This source does not work.

Does this source work with ECMA script 6 only?

Comment: You have to run it as windowed mode (the litlle blue icon just below the github button at the top-right corner of the page)

Comment: @Kaiido
I am now testing on mobile chrome because the microphone is not connected to the PC.
The source does not work in window mode in mobile chrome.
I accept the microphone input but then it doesn't work.